# Sliding effects in Multiple choice quiz in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-dialog, android-sliding

I am facing a problem in a Multiple choice quiz app where there in only one activity showing all the questions one by one.
Current scenario: A multiple choice question appears on the screen, if answer is correct then it will show a Dialog box then dialog box close after some delay and load the next question in the same activity.
What problem I am facing is: If I want to load next question (if answer is correct) which appear as the question is sliding-in from the right direction (not by swiping) automatically after closing of the dialog box in the same activity, how can I proceed for the same? Any pointers?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any pointers for the above question? Need help of the Experts...

Comment: how you are storing your data ?

Comment: I am storing my questions and answers in an array. There is a counter which increments with every question display on the screen.

Comment: HEY, Can you show me your code ? so i can learn it and find better answer  for you.

Comment: Hi @chintan, rather than having sliding effects, I have created the same in custom Dialog bo because I was not able to think of a good solution.